# Status changes email notification flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, email-notification

I have created a simple workflow with Power Automated. On my SP list, I have a column called **Task** **Status** with two options. In-Progress (default) and Completed. I want to achieve is when the users change the Task Status to completed, their manager receives an email.
My issue is no matter what I select I still receive the email.

Kind Regards

[image]

Comment: Can you print the task status column value before condition ?

Comment: I made a silly mistake. Instead of selecting task status value, I was determining task status. It is all good now. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

In the **Condition** action, please select "**Task Status Value**" instead of "Task Status".

[image]